# How to make a DAX formula respond to a Timeline slider?

Tags: excel, slider, dax, timeline

In Excel, I have a source table (named 'Cumulative Events') with columns **Case_num**, **PT**, and **Receipt_Date**. I have a pivot table with a DAX formula `denom = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Cumulative Events'[Case_num]), ALL('Cumulative Events'))`.  When I put PT in the Rows field of my pivot table and *denom* in the Values field, I get the exact same number in the the resulting denom column (ie, the number of unique values in the **Case_num** column in the source table). So far, this is exactly the what I want.

However, when I insert a Timeline slider (linked to **Receipt_Date**) the numbers don't change, and I want them to.

For example, when I use this DAX formula in the Values field, `num = DISTINCTCOUNT('Cumulative Events'[Case_num])`, the numbers change as I adjust the Timeline.  How can I tweak the *denom* formula so that it too responds to the Timeline slider?

(FYI, my ultimate aim is to use a DAX formula *num/denom* that is responsive to the Timeline--so both components need to behave that way.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ALL` function removes all filter context, including any filtering your timeline slicer is doing.

If you want the denominator to respond to the timeline, then you could try [`ALLSELECTED`](https://dax.guide/allselected/) instead.

```
denom =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Cumulative Events'[Case_num] ),
    ALLSELECTED ( 'Cumulative Events' )
)
```